# End-to-Site VPN from IPv4 -Host to IPV6 (only) - Site

Tags: vpn, ipv6, ipv4

I want my IPv4 only Clients to my IPv6 only Site. I have a dualstack Server which I could use as a gateway.

There is a Question somewhat related here:

[IPv6-only client to IPv6/IPv4 dual stack server tunnel?](https://serverfault.com/questions/326132/ipv6-only-client-to-ipv6-ipv4-dual-stack-server-tunnel)

but was asked about 4 years ago.

Is this setup possible:

```
< Hosts >  --- IPv4 --- < DS GatewayServer > --- IPv6 --- < Site >
```

Do I have to set up a host to site VPN to the GatewayServer and a Site to Site VPN to the Site? Can this be done? And how would I route beween the two VPNs?

Comment: Which application layer protocols do you need to use? I have implemented [a name based proxy](http://v4-frontend.netiter.com/), which can handle http, https, and smtp (also ssh if you are willing to patch the client).

Comment: I thought of site like in factory not like in website. So I need some kind of VPN proxy. But your proxy might come in handy for other problems - thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you need is a 6in4 tunnel. If you have a routed prefix on your dual stack server, then you can set up your own tunnel server. Otherwise you can use one of the many free [tunnel providers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IPv6_tunnel_brokers).

Based on my overall experience with various providers, I recommend [Hurricane Electric](https://tunnelbroker.net/).

You could replace the 6in4 tunnel with a site-to-site VPN. The difference between 6in4 and VPN is that the VPN provides integrity and encryption on the path between IPv4 site and tunnel server, but this may not add a lot of value for you, as the path between tunnel server and IPv6 site remains unencrypted.

A site-to-site VPN between IPv4 site and IPv6 site might be possible, but this would obviously add another layer of complexity since the VPN would have to run on top of a tunnel, proxy, or NAT.

Comment: Can I find out if I have a routed prefix? Its a rented vServer

Comment: @MaximilianKindshofer The easiest way to find out is by asking the hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run a reverse proxy on your dual stack host that acts like a server to the IPv4 clients and as a client to the IPv6 server. Which tools to use depends on the protocol you need to handle. I have used `haproxy` with good results for TCP based protocols, and it has extra features for HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: Based on comments, I don't think that is what he wants.